# Getting PHP's Pspell to return corrected word as a variable

Tags: php, spell-checking

I have this script:

```
<?php
ob_start();
$get = $_GET['q'];
$pspell = pspell_new('en','canadian','','utf-8',PSPELL_FAST);

function spellCheckWord($word) {
    global $pspell;
    $autocorrect = TRUE;
    $word = $word[0];  
    if (preg_match('/^[A-Z]*$/',$word)) return $word;
    if (pspell_check($pspell,$word)) return $word;
    if ($autocorrect && $suggestions = pspell_suggest($pspell,$word))
    return '<u>'.current($suggestions).'</u>';
    return '<b>'.$word.'</b>';
};

function spellCheck($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\b\w+\b/','spellCheckWord',$string);
};

$var = ob_get_clean();
echo $get."<br>";
echo $var;
?>
```

I want the corrected string put into a variable from my function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a complete misunderstanding of PHP syntax. returning a string from a function does NOT output the string. None of your functions do any actual output (echo, printf, etc...) so there is NOTHING for the output buffer to capture. AS well, there is nothing in this script which would require buffering to take place, so that's just some useless code.

Your spell check functions are also NOT being executed. So in essence, this entire script does NOTHING except echo out a _GET parameter.

```
<?php

$get = $_GET['q'];

function spellCheckWord($word) {
    $pspell = pspell_new('en','canadian','','utf-8',PSPELL_FAST);
    ...
}

function spellCheck($string) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/\b\w+\b/','spellCheckWord',$string);
}
echo $get, "<br>";
echo spellCheck($word);
```